# PHP Remove Final Comma From Array Output

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm working on a project for Amazon Echo and the output of the code needs to be in a very specific format. Right now code takes a RSS feed and outputs in the form of JSON. The issue I'm running into is the I need a comma at the end of each foreach array item displayed but I can't have a comma at the end.

What's the best way for the final comma not to show?

```
                [
            {"titleText" : "TestTi","uid" :
 "https://feedity.com/hop.aspx?MzMwMzQy4%2BXKKCkpsNLXLy8v1ytOLkpNzC1OTixI1UvOz9XPKMnN0S%2FOrIhPy0lML45PB8qWxCemlKXmlZQWpeoBpQE%3D","updateDate": 
    "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z","mainText" :
         "Six Flags Great Adventure - Justice League Construction Update"},{"titleText" : "TestTi","uid" : "https://feedity.com/hop.aspx?MzMwMzQy4%2BXKKCkpsNLXLy8v1ytOLkpNzC1OTixI1UvOz9XPKMnN0S9PzCmJT8kszkutjC%2FPL8pJiS9KLc4vKtEDygIA",
    "updateDate": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z","mainText" : 
    "Walt Disney World - Ever Heard of Disney Mountain?!"},]
```

I need to remove that final comma displayed.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php

header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
?>

[
<?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument();
    $rss->load('http://feedity.com/screamscape-com/VVNVUlFV.rss');
    $feed = array();
    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
    $limit = 2;
    for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
        $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
        $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
        $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];

        echo '{"titleText" : "TestTi",';
        echo '"uid" : "'.$link.'",';
        echo '"updateDate": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z",';
        echo '"mainText" : "'.$title.'"},';


    }
?>
]
```

Comment: One function - `json_encode`

Comment: create new array in "for loop" width content and `impole(',', $array);` or use json_encode();

Comment: You're defining `$description` but your not using it. Do you want your output for json to just be `titleText`, `uid`, `updateDate` and `mainText` for each item?

Answer (score 4):

The best way would be to build the array and output it using `json_encode()`.  That way you don't have to try and manually create the json.

### Simplified Example

```
$feed = array();

$results = array();
foreach($feed as $item){
    $results[] => array(
        'titleText' => 'TestTi',
        'uid' => $item['link'],
        'title' => $item['title']
    );
}
$json = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: I was previously using that but the output from it would add "{"item":" to the start of the output and an extra "}" at the end which I couldn't figure out how to stop.

Comment: I've added a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array();
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $arr[] = '{"titleText" : "TestTi", "uid" : "'.$link.'", "updateDate": "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z", "mainText" : "'.$title.'"}';
}
print implode(',', $arr);
```